# php SELECT query from five tables each with client_id in first field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have five tables; client, sectionone, sectiontwo, sectionthree, sectionfour. Each table populates a client_id in the first field automatically from when data is being entered.
I want to retrieve the percent field for each table (sectionone, sectiontwo, sectionthree, sectionfour) for the particular client that is on the site. My query works and retrieves the percent field for each table, but unfortunately it keeps returning this for the first client in the database, for example client_id 1. 
How can I change my query below so that I get the percentage returned for the current client? Thank you so much for your help. Rosie

```
$query = "SELECT a.client_id,
       a.percent,
       b.percent,
       c. percent,
       d. percent
FROM sectionone a,
     sectiontwo b,
     sectionthree c,
     sectionfour d
WHERE a.client_id = b.client_id
  AND b.client_id = c.client_id
  AND c.client_id = d.client_id";
```

Comment: You should add a client_id=$actual_client_id condition.

Comment: Thanks so much Lajos Veres. I'm going to go away and try that, cheers, Rosie

Comment: Hello again Lajos Veres, can you show me how you would add your suggestion? I have tried variations but keep getting an error message. I'm clearly not too good with this. I added it into the WHERE a.client_id = actual_client_id

Comment: I posted a full answer. (Comments doesn't support code highlighting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question whether your `sectionone`, `sectiontwo`, etc, tables have exactly one row for each client.

The possible situations are these.

1. precise one - to - one relationship between `client` and `sectionone`, etc.
2. one - to - zero-or-one relationship
3. one - to - zero-one-or-many relationship

Reading between the lines of your question, it looks to me like you believe you have the first situation, but you actually have the third.  That is, you might have multiple `sectionthree` rows for a particular client id.

What you want in your resultset is a single row for each client looking like this.

```
  clientid      one      two     three    four
  123           45       55      20       56
```

It's important for a query like this to visualize clearly what resultset you want. But you knew that.

So, here we go.  We need to summarize the `sectionX` tables one by one, because we have to create the illusion that they have exactly one row per client, even if they don't.

```
    SELECT client_id, AVG(percent) AS percent
      FROM sectionone
     GROUP BY client_id
```

The same query works for all four of your `sectionX` tables. We'll use four of these summary queries as *virtual tables* for the rest of the main query.

Next, we have to JOIN these four summary queries to the `client` table. We should use LEFT JOIN commands to cover the case where a `sectionX` table might contain zero rows for the particular client.

```
   SELECT z.client_id, a.percent AS one,   b.percent AS two, 
                       c.percent AS three, d.percent AS four
     FROM client as z
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT client_id, AVG(percent) AS percent
      FROM sectionone
     GROUP BY client_id
          ) AS a ON z.client_id = a.client_id
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT client_id, AVG(percent) AS percent
      FROM sectiontwo
     GROUP BY client_id
          ) AS b ON z.client_id = b.client_id
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT client_id, AVG(percent) AS percent
      FROM sectionthree
     GROUP BY client_id
          ) AS c ON z.client_id = c.client_id
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT client_id, AVG(percent) AS percent
      FROM sectionfour
     GROUP BY client_id
          ) AS d ON z.client_id = d.client_id
```

Finally, if you want just one client_id, you should end your query with

```
     WHERE z.client_id = whatever
```

If there's more than one row in a `sectionX` table for a client, this approach takes the average of their values. If you need something else, like MAX, MIN, etc, you can use that instead in the query.

This looks complicated, but it's actually quite simple, if you can call a five-way table LEFT JOIN simple :-).  It works correctly for all three cases mentioned at the beginning of this answer.

What's more, MySQL (and other SQL systems) do a pretty good job of optimizing this kind of query because it's quite common.

Comment: Hello again Ollie, I just want to retrieve the one client on the one row. I tried therefore to add into my WHERE statement a.client_id = actual_client_id but getting an error message. Can you say how this WHERE statement should look and does it go before the other conditions or after them? Thanks, Rosie

Comment: Rosie, I can't tell what's wrong without seeing your entire WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT a.client_id,
       a.percent,
       b.percent,
       c. percent,
       d. percent
FROM sectionone a,
     sectiontwo b,
     sectionthree c,
     sectionfour d
WHERE a.client_id = b.client_id
  AND b.client_id = c.client_id
  AND c.client_id = d.client_id
  AND a.client_id = 1
";
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me where to add the condition ie a.client_id = 1. My problem though is, it is already returning the first client even when client x is live on the webpage. I want it to return the actual client who is on the webpage. Would a.client_id = '' do it do you think? What can I replace (1) with? Appreciate, Rosie

Comment: You should know from somewhere which user is actually on your page. The "general" solution is to log in the user, save the user id into the session, and use the saved user id in queries like this. There are good tutorials in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help and I now have the answer which is working:

```
$query = "SELECT a.client_id,
   a.percent,
   b.percent,
   c. percent,
   d. percent
FROM sectionone a,
 sectiontwo b,
 sectionthree c,
 sectionfour d
WHERE a.client_id = b.client_id
AND b.client_id = c.client_id
AND c.client_id = d.client_id
```

additional code added

```
ORDER BY client_id DESC";
```

This provides the results for the current user. Very happy, Rosie